# "Configure application insights" not showing in VS2017 and how to view insights locally in VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-application-insights

We have recently upgraded the visual studio from 2015 to 2017 pro.

In visual studio 2015,we have implemented application insights and that was working fine.

After upgraded to 2017, the option "Configure application insights" not showing in solution explorer.

I have reinstalled Microsoft.ApplicationInsights and Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web packages. but no use, which is not showing.

Please suggest the steps to check application insights locally using visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refering to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/quick-monitor-portal#prerequisites), you have to install the following workloads for Visual Studio 2017:

- ASP.NET and web development
- Azure development

Comment: Thanks Martin. It is working after updating vs2017 with mentioned workloads!

Comment: Somehow, I am unable to see this option - I do have "ASP.NET and Web development", and "Azure development" workloads enabled. Using VS 2017 Enterprise edition v15.9.4

Answer (score 0):

Being more specific, do you need the pack **Developer Analytics Tools** from *ASP.NET and web development*